# Install obspy in cygwin

Tags: python, linux, cygwin

I am new in Cygwin and currently I am trying to install a module obspy in python, but I have the following problems:

```
$ easy_install obspy-0.9.0-py2.6-win32.egg
Processing obspy-0.9.0-py2.6-win32.egg
creating /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obspy-0.9.0-py2.6-win32.egg
Extracting obspy-0.9.0-py2.6-win32.egg to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding obspy 0.9.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing obspy-mseed-recordanalyzer script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-scan script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-dataless2xseed script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-reftek-rescue script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-xseed2dataless script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-indexer script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-print script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-runtests script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-dataless2resp script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-plot script to /usr/bin
Installing obspy-mopad script to /usr/bin

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obspy-0.9.0-py2.6-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for obspy==0.9.0
Searching for obspy==0.9.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/obspy/
Best match: obspy 0.9.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/o/obspy/obspy-0.9.0.zip#md5=f720f675e66e8b2b6518e41b9ab9ada4
Processing obspy-0.9.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-RfU4Qv/obspy-0.9.0/setup.cfg
Running obspy-0.9.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-RfU4Qv/obspy-0.9.0/egg-dist-tmp-FLcOHj
error: Setup script exited with error: mismatch of extension names: build/libtau_CYGWIN_NT-5.1_32bit_py27.pyf provides 'libtau_CYGWIN_NT' but expected '1_32bit_py27'
```

To tell the truth I do not quite understand the problem and how to fix it. Does somebody maybe have some ideas?

I am running:

cygwin = 1.7.28(0.271/5/3)

python = 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09) [GCC 4.5.3]

Thx

Answer (score 0):

obspy constructs a system-dependent extension name based on the value of `platform.system()`, which is equal to `uname -s`.  On Cygwin, that would be e.g. `CYGWIN_NT-6.1` (depending on the version of Windows; `-WOW64` is also added for i686 Cygwin on Windows x64).  The issue is that a Python module name cannot contain a hyphen nor a dot (the latter of which is a namespace indicator).

Therefore, you will have to install this manually from source after making some modifications.  I recommend using `sys.platform` (which is just `cygwin`) instead of `platform.system()` wherever it is used in a library name substitution; that does require adding a few `import sys` where not already `import`ed.

Once you do that, you'll find that the included libmseed does not compile due to conflicting typedefs.  Fixing that requires adding a `|| defined(__CYGWIN__)` to either the Linux or BSD conditionals in `obspy/mseed/src/libmseed/lmplatform.h`.

I have made the complete patch available [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/python-obspy/ci/master/tree/0.9.0-cygwin.patch).

Comment: Thx for your reponse. In my case I solved the problem by installing older version of obspy: easy_install obspy-0.8.4-py2.7-win32.egg. In this case I did not have any problems. Now it works.